# Isbusy shows up on top of the screen

Tags: c#, tizen

In Tizen mobile emulator the IsBusy icon shows up on top of the screen which dose not look good. Is there any solution to control the position of the Isbusy icon? I am using Xamarin forms with c#.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use Grid,Absolute,relative layouts to achieve this

For example:

```
    <AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <!--<Page XAML Content/>-->
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       Color="#3a63bd"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```